# Shortcut keys for conversations

Tags: guild-wars-2

I am a keyboard guy. I move and fight with keyboard mostly. But when I enter a conversation. There doesn't seem to be a way to pick answers with the keyboard...I have to go get the mouse. Anyone know a trick to answer conversations (e.g. quests) with the keyboard?

Answer (score 3):

It's not listed under [Controls](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Controls) so I think sadly it might not be available. I've looked for it myself without any success.